# Why does my database attribute keep getting reset in IndexDB?

Tags: javascript, database, class, indexeddb

I'm a student and I've been tasked with creating a todo application with clientside authentication using IndexedDB.

I'm trying to store account data, but my database attribute keeps setting itself back to null even after working during the onupgradeneeded method. I've been using debuggers and it doesn't actually show my code running the onupgradeneeded method, though it does as it creates the correct stores on Firefox.

Any help will be appreciated!

Many thanks

```js
class DatabaseConnection
{
    constructor(name="todoapp", version=1) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
        this.database = null;

        // Normalise IndexedDB by switching versions depending on browser
        var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

        // If the browser does not support IndexedDB, do not load
        if(!indexedDB) document.write("Your browser does not support IndexedDB. Please try another browser.");
        else console.log(`Database [${name}] successfully loaded.`);

        /* Instead of using anonymous functions in the constructor, I'm going to use private methods in the class
        for organisational and performance purposes */
        var request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
        request.onerror = this._onerror;
        request.onsuccess = this._onsuccess;
        request.onupgradeneeded = this._onupgradeneeded;
    }

    /* Account methods
    =================== */

    registerAccount() {
        console.log(this);
        let tx = this.database.transaction(["accounts"], "readwrite");

        let account = {
            username: "George",
            password: "Test"
        };

        tx.objectStore("accounts").add(account);
    }

    /* Private methods
    =================== */

    _onerror(event) {
        alert("[ERROR] :: " + event.target.error);
    }

    _onsuccess(event) {
        this.database = event.target.result;
    }

    _onupgradeneeded(event) {
        this.database = event.target.result;

        // Defining the data used in the database
        this.database.createObjectStore("todos", {
            keyPath: "id",
            autoIncrement: true
        });
        this.database.createObjectStore("accounts", {
            keyPath: "id",
            autoIncrement: true
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callbacks aren't "bound", so they will be called with a different value for `this` than you are expecting.

If you do `console.log(this)` from inside your callbacks, you'll see what's going on, and why `this.database = ...` isn't working as you expect.

Try this:

```
request.onsuccess = this._onsuccess.bind(this);
request.onupgradeneeded = this._onupgradeneeded.bind(this);
```

... which turns your function into one that automagically has `this` set to what you want.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Sorry if it was a stupid question.